# how to get sku in template

Tags: magento2, php, sku

I want get sku

```
<?php echo __('Product code') . ": " . $item->getSku(); ?>
```

This is my code, it not work

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<?php
/** @var \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Items $block */
$columns = $block->getColumns();
?>

<div class="products-grid wishlist">
    <?php if (count($block->getItems())) : ?>
    <ol class="product-items">
        <?php foreach ($block->getItems() as $item) : ?>
        <li data-row="product-item" class="product-item" id="item_<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($item->getId()) ?>">
            <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">
                <?php foreach ($columns as $column) : ?>
                <?= $column->setItem($item)->toHtml();?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="product-sku">
                <?php echo __('Product code') . ": " . $item->getSku(); ?>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <?php else : ?>
    <div class="message info empty">
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('This Wish List has no Items')) ?></span>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?php foreach ($columns as $column) : ?>
<?= $column->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In product
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2 Query to get SKU, Product Details ,more information](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202012/magento-2-query-to-get-sku-product-details-more-information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please call it like below. It will work for sure.

```
<?php echo __('Product code') . ": " . $item->getProduct()->getSku(); ?>
```

Please check screen shot:- https://prnt.sc/16f6gn0

Cheers!

Comment: It work, Thank you